# Liquibase and programmatic changes?

Tags: liquibase

Is it possible to record changes you did programmatically? I.e. say you updated a table through a Java program using JDBC. How will those changes end up in the Liquibase change log(ledger of changes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changes are made outside of liquibase, the primary way of adding that change to the changelog is by using the `diffChangeLog` command. This is not always 100% accurate, and should not be relied on in most cases.

The process is documented at https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html and the reason why you should be cautious in its use is described at https://www.liquibase.org/quickstart.html

Here is a relevant quote from that page:

> While Liquibase is capable of comparisons (or diffs), it is fundamentally a migration-based solution. The diff capability in Liquibase is only meant to assist with onboarding new projects and with sanity checking that database migrations have been properly applied.

Comment: Understood. I thought that Liquibase would offer some kind of JDBC wrapper where you could update a table from a Java program and have this change added to the change log.